# Discord RestCord add role

Tags: php, restcord

I am using the Discord RestCord PHP, and my current code looks like this:

```
$client = new DiscordClient([
        'token' => 'TOKEN' //discord token
      ]);
      
        $client->guild->addGuildMember([
            'guild.id' => (int)$guildid, //discord server id
            'user.id' => (int)$discord_id,
            'access_token' => (string)$token,
            'nick' => (string)$sessionuser,
            'roles' => array(770010213469519913) //discord roles
        ]);
```

But this is only for adding members which means they need to have not joined the discord before, is there any way for people who are already in the discord but needs their roles updated according to what role they are on forums like if you click the link but it detects that you are already in it, and then sets your roles to desired role?

Is this dooable with RestCord? There's not much docs about it and only handful of examples on their website.

I'd appriciate if anyone can point me or show me in the right direction, regards.